# Unable to update state in redux when using @reduxjs/toolkit

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-toolkit

I currently started learning redux. My code was working perfectly with core redux, then I tried out @reduxjs/toolkit and now I'm unable to access the function to change the state in the store. Here is my code of reducer.

```
const seasonEdits = createSlice({
  name: "seasons",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addSeason(state, action) {
      state.push(action.payload);
      console.log("this here");
    },
    removeSeason(state, action) {
      state.filter((season) => season.id !== action.payload);
    },
    markComplete(state, action) {
      state.map((season) => {
        if (season.id == action.payload) season.isWatched = !season.isWatched;
      });
    },
  },
});

export const { addSeason, removeSeason, markComplete } = seasonEdits.actions;
export default seasonEdits.reducer;
```

and my store.js file

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

import seasonReducer from "./reducer";

export default store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    seasons: seasonReducer,
  },
});
```

and the add.js file which has add functionality. Calling a **handleSubmit** function which is creating an object and adding it to an array which is the state in store.

```
 const handleSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      if (!name || !totalNoSeason) {
        return alert("Please add both fields");
      }

      const seasonToAdd = {
        id: shortid.generate(),
        name,
        totalNoSeason,
        isWatched: false,
      };

      addSeason(seasonToAdd);

      navigation.navigate("Home");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addSeason: (data) => dispatch(addSeason(data)),
  };
};

Add.propTypes = {
  addSeason: propTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Add);
```

Comment: Change `mapDispatchToProps` to `const mapDispatchToProps = { addSeason }`

Comment: @MuhammadNoumanRafique that wasn't working either, I have already tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `array.map()` and `array.filter`() return *new* arrays!  Right now your reducers are calling those functions, and then just throwing away the new arrays:

```
removeSeason(state, action) {
  // The return value is thrown away and ignored!      
  state.filter((season) => season.id !== action.payload);
},
```

You need to *return* the new value:

```
removeSeason(state, action) {
  // Now RTK will see the new return value      
  return state.filter((season) => season.id !== action.payload);
},
```

See https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#resetting-and-replacing-state for more details.

Comment: thanks returning the value worked.